# How to convert months as factors while still maintaining the months in sequence?

Tags: r, lubridate

I have a original data frame (df) containing data of around 10 years(1994-2003). The head(df) is as shown below:

```
Sl.no       Date Year Month Season            val1            val2     val3
1     1 1993-12-01 1993   Dec Winter          21.0            16.0      3.0
2     2 1994-01-01 1994   Jan Winter          21.0            15.5      0.0
3     3 1994-02-01 1994   Feb Winter          21.0            18.5      0.0
4     4 1994-03-01 1994   Mar Spring          30.0            24.0      1.9
5     5 1994-04-01 1994   Apr Spring          35.5            27.0      0.5
6     6 1994-05-01 1994   May Spring          36.0            30.0      1.5
```

since i wanted to convert Months as factors, so as to plot boxplot, i used:

```
df$Month <- as.factor(format(df$Date, "%b"))
levels(df$Month) <- c("Jan","Feb","Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul",
"Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec")
```

however the output appeared as below: (Months were not in sequence like original df)

```
Sl.no       Date Year Month Season          val1             val2      val3
1     1 1993-12-01 1993   Mar Winter          21.0            16.0      3.0
2     2 1994-01-01 1994   May Winter          21.0            15.5      0.0
3     3 1994-02-01 1994   Apr Winter          21.0            18.5      0.0
4     4 1994-03-01 1994   Aug Spring          30.0            24.0      1.9
5     5 1994-04-01 1994   Jan Spring          35.5            27.0      0.5
6     6 1994-05-01 1994   Sep Spring          36.0            30.0      1.5
```

so in the above df, it is noted that the months are distorted, which otherwise should be in sequence following the Date.

so how can i rectify this problem? your help will be highly appreciated.
kind regards

Comment: `df$Month <- factor(format(df$Date, "%b"), month.abb, ordered = TRUE)`?

Comment: @A5C1D2H2I1M1N2O1R2T1 care to post it as an answer?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik, done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
df$Month <- factor(format(df$Date, "%b"), month.abb, ordered = TRUE)
```

Demo of the problem you're facing:

```
set.seed(1)
M <- sample(month.abb, 20, TRUE)
M
#  [1] "Apr" "May" "Jul" "Nov" "Mar" "Nov" "Dec" "Aug" "Aug" "Jan" "Mar" "Mar" "Sep" "May"
# [15] "Oct" "Jun" "Sep" "Dec" "May" "Oct"

your_attempt <- as.factor(M)
#  [1] Apr May Jul Nov Mar Nov Dec Aug Aug Jan Mar Mar Sep May Oct Jun Sep Dec May Oct
# Levels: Apr Aug Dec Jan Jul Jun Mar May Nov Oct Sep

## At this step, you're basically asking R to replace "Apr" with "Jan",
##   "Aug" with "Feb", and so on. Not what you're looking for....
levels(your_attempt) <- c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", 
                          "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec")

your_attempt
#  [1] Jan Aug May Sep Jul Sep Mar Feb Feb Apr Jul Jul Nov Aug Oct Jun Nov Mar Aug Oct
# Levels: Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec

## ordered = TRUE not necessarily required. Depends on what you want to do
new_attempt <- factor(M, levels = month.abb, ordered = TRUE)
new_attempt
#  [1] Apr May Jul Nov Mar Nov Dec Aug Aug Jan Mar Mar Sep May Oct Jun Sep Dec May Oct
# Levels: Jan < Feb < Mar < Apr < May < Jun < Jul < Aug < Sep < Oct < Nov < Dec
```

Answer (score 1):

the `month()` function from the [lubridate package](https://lubridate.tidyverse.org/reference/month.html) will handle this for you.

```
library(lubridate)
df$Month <- month(df$Date, label=TRUE, abbr=TRUE)
```